# Is $2^n$ a Friedman number for all $n>9$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

It appears to me that all numbers in the form $2^n$ for $n>9$ where $n$ is a whole number are [Friedman numbers](https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/0800.html) (that is, positive integers which can be written in some nontrivial way using their own digits, together with the symbols $+$, $–$, $\times$, $/$, exponentiation, parentheses and concatenation). For example,
\begin{align*}
2^{10} = 1024 ={} & 4^{10/2}, \\
2^{11} = 2048 ={} & \frac{8^4}{(2+0)}, \\   
2^{12} = 4096 ={} & (4+0\cdot 9)^6, \\
2^{13} = 8192 ={} & 8\cdot 2^{9+1}.
\end{align*}

Is it an open question whether all powers of two greater than $2^9$ are Friedman numbers? Is there a counterexample, or do we have a proof?

Comment: Tabulated, with some links and references, at https://oeis.org/A036057

Comment: For reference: $16384=2^{14}=8^{6+1-3}*4, 32768=2^{15}=2^{(8-6)^3+7}, 65536=2^{16}=(6/3)^{5+5+6}, 131072=2^{17}=2^{17+0*13}, 262144=2^{18}=2^{6+4*2+4*1}, 524288=2^{19}=2^{5*4-2+(8/8)}, 1048576=2^{20}=4^{10+8+5-7-6}$.

Comment: Additionally, I'd expect powers of $2$ to eventually always be Friedman numbers; eventually, it should always be possible to get $2$ from the digits, (assuming you can't het too many $0$s, or $0^0=1$ is allowed, as then pigeonhole will be enough) and the rest will be about getting the power, which I expect to be possible for large enough $n$ (although I don't have a full argument for that part).

Comment: It certainly seems likely, but this seems very hard to prove since e.g. AFAIK we don't even have a substantial lower bound on the number of nonzero digits in powers of two.

Comment: The examples are unpleasant to read because the equations are separated by a mere period which looks like a multiplication symbol. I can honestly say I was confused at first. A general rule of good writing is not to begin a sentence with a mathematical symbol immediately after ending a sentence with a mathematical symbol.

Comment: From Friedman's page: "Ulrich Schimke conjectures that for every $k$ which is not a power of $10$, $k^n$ is a Friedman number for arbitrarily large $n$. He notes that $2^n$ appears to be a Friedman number for all $n>9$."

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we say $n^0=1$ for each digit $n$ (including $n=0$):

Write $n$ in binary. Then we can write $2^n=2^{\sum_{j=0}^k a_i 2^i} = 2^{(...((a_k)*2+a_{k-1})*2+a_{k-2})...)+a_0+0*r}$ for any $r$ (we use $r$ to use up any remaining divits). We can write each $0$ using one equal pair, $2$ using $6$ digits, as long as they include $2$ equal pairs, and each $a_i$ either using no digits (if $0$) or 2 equal digits (if $1$). Therefore, to write $n$, we will need $3k+3$ equal pairs and $k+3$ additional digits. For $k>7$, this takes $7k+9$ digits.

The number of digits in $2^n$ is at least $3n/10$. This is true for $n>237$, so for $n>237$, $2^n$ is Friedman. This bound is nowhere near tight, so it is likely that you can get something in thr 10s by adjusting this methodology, and maybe $9$ by checking.

It's possible I made some arithmetic errors, but the proof outline should ok.